# Summing a variable across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I need to sum values across multiple sheets. The sheets will always have different names as they are set by the date.

I have a summary sheet as the first sheet in my workbook.

From a field in my summary sheet, I'd like to read through each sheet and if the value of the fields match it adds the values together.

For example, pseudo code would be, Go through each worksheet and if `SummarySheet.Range("A24").value` is in range(G1:G200) sum up the corresponding cell in range("H1:H200").

I've tried sum if and sum product.

I've tried the below code. Which bombed!

```
For Each Cell In Range("A24:A224")
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
  For Each i In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("G2:H200")
    If Cell.Value = i.Value Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Cell.Value = Cell.Value + i.Value
    End If
  Next i
  Next ws
  Next Cell
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"Which bombed!"*? What's the error message?

Comment: There wasn't one, it just moved the active cell numerous times. I think what I'm after could be a pivot table where when the user creates a new worksheet, that worksheets range is automatically added to the pivot tables data on the summary sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is referencing "ActiveSheet" and "ActiveCell" but it's not activating anything within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to guess what your code is trying to do.  This answer is more about good coding practice than specific recommendations.  My hope is this will allow you to correct your own code.

`ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select` serves no purpose.  The ActiveCell is the cell containing the cursor.  You do not position the cursor at the beginning of the routine to a first cell and you neither read from nor write to the ActiveCell during the rest of the macro.

`For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` serves no purpose since you do not use `ws`. In `For Each i In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("G2:H200")` did you mean to write `For Each i In ws.Range("G2:H200")`?  I cannot see anywhere else you might have meant to use `ws`.

`Each Cell In Range("A24:A224")` references the ActiveSheet.  This is whatever worksheet happens to be active when the macro was started.  My guess is that `Range("A24:A224")` is in the summary worksheet.  If the user happens to be looking at another worksheet when they start the macro, that other worksheet is the ActiveSheet and not the summary worksheet.  I assume you want to accumulate totals in the summary worksheet.  If the wrong worksheet is active when the macro is started, that worksheet will be corrupted beyond recovery.  UnDo cannot undo what a macro has done so you will have to revert to the previous copy of the workbook.  I hope you create a new copy of the workbook before trying experimental macros so you can revert to an undamaged version.  You need something like:

```
Dim WshtSumm As Worksheet

Set WshtSumm = Worksheets("Summary")

For Each Cell In WshtSumm.Range("A24:A224")
   :      :      :      :      :      :      :
Next
```

In my opinion, you should not use names like `Cell` because it is too similar to the reserved word `Cells`.  You should not use names like `i` because such names are meaningless.  Perhaps it does not matter in such a small macro but, as your macros get bigger, meaningful names will be a real help when you or someone else looks at this macro in six or twelve months.  Few macros last unchanged for ever; they are updated every few months to address changing requirements.  I do not know what `Cell` and `i` represent but perhaps `CellSumm` and `CellData` would be better names.

Consider `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` and `Range("A24:A224")`.  I have just told you that you should have identified which worksheet holds `Range("A24:A224")`.  This was because your workbook holds several worksheets any of which could be active.  If you have a workbook that has only one worksheet, `Range("A24:A224")` might be OK.  Personally, I avoid unqualified ranges because it is so easy to add a new worksheet.  However, is it likely that you will have two workbooks or more workbooks open?  Yes, it is possible to run a macro in one workbook from another workbook but is this likely?  `ThisWorkbook` identifies the workbook holding the macro.  If you are concerned that the wrong workbook will be active, you are absolutely correct to specify which collection of worksheets you wish to access because each workbook has its own collection.  However, `Worksheets` on its own will normally be sufficient.  This is something you need to think about, particularly as your macros get more complicated: do I need to qualify this range or worksheet or anything of which you might have more than one?

Consider:

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
  For Each i In ws.Range("G2:H200")
```

I have not qualified `ws` because a worksheet has a property `Parent` which identifies its workbook.  You qualified `ws` when you created it.

One of the worksheets in `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` will be the summary worksheet.  Do you want to examine cells in the summary worksheet?  I assume not.  You need something like:

```
Dim WshtSumm As Worksheet
Dim WshtOther As Worksheet

Set WshtSumm = Worksheets("Summary")

For Each WshtOther In Worksheets
  If WshtOther.Name <> WshtSumm.Name Then
     :      :      :      :      :      :      :
  End If
Next
```

This code only examines worksheets whose name does not match the summary worksheet's name.  Whenever you look through an entire collection of something, you need to ask yourself: do I really want to look at everyone?

Consider:

```
If Cell.Value = i.Value Then
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
  Cell.Value = Cell.Value + i.Value
End If
```

Where you have written `ActiveCell`, I suspect you meant `Cell` giving:

```
If Cell.Value = i.Value Then
  Cell.Offset(0, 1).Select
  Cell.Value = Cell.Value + i.Value
End If
```

This would make a little more sense but not much.  You search Range("G2:H200") of every worksheet for a value that matches a value in Range("A24:A224") of the summary worksheet.  If you find that matching value you add it to the next cell in Range("A24:A224").  You tell us nothing about the summary worksheet or the data worksheets so this may be sensible but it does not feel sensible.  If you find a match on "A30", you add the value of "A30" to "A31".  But then you search for a match on the amended "A31".  I cannot imagine any requirement for which this would be sensible.

Even if I thought this was sensible, I don’t think it will work.  If I write:

```
For X = 1 to 10
     :      :
Next
```

I cannot change the value of X within the For Loop.  I have not tried recently but my recollection is that the attempt to change X is ignored.  You are trying to change the equivalent of X for a For Each statement.  I have not tried but I suspect your attempt to change `Cell` will fail.  Even if it can change `Cell` you should not.  `Select` is a slow command and you should only use it if it is essential.  Try something like:

```
If Cell.Value = i.Value Then
  Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value + i.Value
End If
```

I hope the above helps.  If it does not, please provide details of the two ranges so I can better understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this and it worked perfect.

```
Sub GenerateTheFormula()
Dim x, Formula
Formula = "=SUM(" 'Formula begins with =SUM(
For x = 3 To Sheets.Count
    Formula = Formula & Sheets(x).Name & "!A1," 'Add SheetName and Cell and Comma
Next x
Formula = Left(Formula, Len(Formula) - 1) & ")" 'Remove trailing comma and add parenthesis
Range("B1").Formula = Formula 'Where do you want to put this formula?
End Sub
```

Idea from here:

[Excel VBA Sum from Multiple Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028767/excel-vba-sum-from-multiple-sheets?rq=1)